# Pass Socat parameters in a file

Tags: socat

I need to build out the socat parameters in a file and have socat retrieve them.  It there a header for this?  I tried socat < parameterfile.txt, but that doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague on details, but let's suppose you want to run:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:10000 -
```

You could create a file called `params.txt` which contains:

```
TCP-LISTEN:1000 -
```

and then run:

```
socat $(cat params.txt)
```

or if you prefer a more terse syntax:

```
socat $(< params.txt)
```